# How to monitor accuracy in tensorflow (metric accuracy is not available)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I would like to monitor accuracy for my tensorflow model, however, when compiling my model using `metrics=['accuracy']` or metrics=`[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]` and then train my model the following Warning pops up.

WARNING:tensorflow: Early stopping conditioned on metric `accuracy` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss, val_loss

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=["tried both options i mentioned"])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=1000)]          
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5000, batch_size=100, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: used both? `metrics=['accuracy', 'loss']`

Comment: I can try it but I don’t see how that would help since loss is already detected as a metric.

Comment: Tried it and it didn’t work.

Comment: Have you tried `metrics=['val_loss']` ?

Comment: How many samples do you have in your dataset?

Comment: I actually have a list of points, about 350 in total.

Comment: I don’t see the point in using metric=[‘val_loss’], Val loss is already detected as a metric and I can use it for early stopping. I would like to use accuracy instead.

Comment: Do you know that the accuracy is a classification metric and is not available for other problems?

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/accuracy#:%7E:text=Accuracy%20is%20one%20metric%20for,predictions%20Total%20number%20of%20predictions):
Accuracy is one metric for evaluating classification models. Informally, accuracy is the fraction of predictions our model got right. Formally, accuracy has the following definition:

[image: accuracy metric formula]

So, for other problems like regression you should use other metrics rather than `accuracy`, like `metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kaveh's answer,  there are other metrics for regression problems. One that I think is quite useful is **R2 squared** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) and it isn't included in Keras.

**Tensorflow addons library** (https://www.tensorflow.org/addons) implements it and can be used in a ANN with the following code:

```py
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss="mean_squared_error",
              metrics=tfa.metrics.RSquare(y_shape=(1,)))
```